# Python Beautifulsoup CSS selector not working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use a CSS selector on a specific tag on the webpage's source.  This is what I have right now:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pprint

r2 = requests.get("http://spot311.calgary.ca/reports/15-00462387")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r2.text, 'html.parser')

pprint(soup.select("blockquote"))
```

On the page source, there is only one tag called "blockquote", but I am getting the error:

```
 pprint(soup.select("blockquote"))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I googled around and turned up some people having issues where they only wrote

```
import BeautifulSoup
```

instead of

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

But I already have

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

which is correct for my python distribution, I know because I have another program that uses this import and it works just fine.

Am I just not using the selector right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import [`pprint()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint) function from `pprint` module.

Replace:

```
import pprint
```

with:

```
from pprint import pprint
```

Comment: Augh, so simple! I just got so tunnel visioned on the beautifulsoup module Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can leave it as

```
import pprint
```

but when you call for it later you must write

```
pprint.pprint((soup.select("blockquote"))
```

In my beginner opinion, i think this is better formatting as it is clearer to see later on in big projects what module that function came from.